# retrieve all documents from firestore as custom objects

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firestore. I have problem in retrieving all the documents from Firestore as custom objects (here its the object Qst). Please help me.

[I'm using Cloud Firestore as follows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNpXB.png)

And my code is :

```
db.collection("questions")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                           // Log.d("state", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                            db.collection("questions").document(document.getId())
                                    .get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                                    Qst q=documentSnapshot.toObject(Qst.class);
                                    Log.d("qst",q.toString());
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d("state", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

and here is my Qst class :

```
public class Qst {

private String qst;
private String[] choiceList;
private int ansIndex;

public Qst(String qst, String[] choiceList, int ansIndex) {
    this.qst = qst;
    this.choiceList = choiceList;
    this.ansIndex = ansIndex;
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, there is not need to get the data twice. You can achieve this, by only using a get() call once. So please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference questionsRef = rootRef.collection("questions");
questionsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Qst qst = document.toObject(Qst.class);
                Log.d("TAG", qst.getQst());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
In what year was Google launched on the web?
//and so on
```

Comment: the class "QueryDocumentSnapshot" is is unknown !!

Comment: use DocumentSnapshot @rincko

Comment: @PeterHaddad Thanks Peter for your comment.

Comment: Yes, Peter is right. This what you need to do. Please change `QueryDocumentSnapshot` to `DocumentSnapshot`. This is possible because `QueryDocumentSnapshot` extends `DocumentSnapshot`. See also my updated answer.

Comment: @AlexMamo the data is retrieved but it does not transform into an object !!
is the class "Qst" set correctly ??

Comment: Good to hear that the data is retrieved! But If you say so, it means that you are getting an object of `Qst` class correctly. Why do you say "it does not transform into an object"? What you are getting from the database, It is already an object of `Qst` class.

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?